# SharpSVN resolve conflict error

Tags: .net, svn, sharpsvn

I'm using SharpSVN with .NET 2 and I cannot seem to resolve conflicts.
The exception message is:
"Can't open file 'conflicted_file.xml.r0': The system cannot find the file specified."
I've checked, and the files are definitely all there and in the right place.

The call I'm making looks like this:
`Dim conflict As SvnStatusEventArgs = someConflictedStatus`
`Dim action As SvnAccept = SvnAccept.Mine`
`svn.Resolve(conflict.FullPath, action, args)`

I've tried everything I can think of.  Am I just doing something wrong?  Has anyone else run across this problem?

The svn info output is:

```
Path: C:\something\conflictedFile.xml
Name: conflictedFile.xml
URL: file:///C:/TestRepo/something/conflictedFile.xml
Repository Root: file:///C:/TestRepo
Repository UUID: 3dab40bf-9741-a042-adb2-b1665333fe3b
Revision: 2
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Rev: 2
Last Changed Date: 2011-04-03 14:27:39 -0400 (Sun, 03 Apr 2011)
Checksum: 2098e127a615e567234d2d09512e17ae
Conflict Previous Base File: conflictedFile.xml.r0
Conflict Previous Working File: conflictedFile.xml.mine
Conflict Current Base File: conflictedFile.xml.r2
```

Comment: What version of Subversion server are you using, 1.5.x or 1.6.x?  Did you make sure your SharpSVN install matches up with your version of Subversion?

Comment: Can you run `svn info` on the conflicted file and share the result of that?

Comment: The svn ver is 1.6.x and the sharpsvn ver does match it.  I've successfully used sharpsvn to do everything else (to so degree), this is the only things I've come across where I can't seem to get any traction.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the svn info function.  Looks like some kind of event handler, but I'm not sure how to extract any useful info from it.

Comment: `svn info` is a commandline for the console command `svn`, which should show a bit more info

Comment: I see.  Heres a synopsis of the results of info:

Comment: Path: C:\something\conflictedFile.xml | 
Name: conflictedFile.xml | 
URL: file:///C:/TestRepo/something/conflictedFile.xml | 
Repository Root: file:///C:/TestRepo | 
Repository UUID: 3dab40bf-9741-a042-adb2-b1665333fe3b | 
Revision: 2 | 
Node Kind: file | 
Schedule: normal | 
Last Changed Rev: 2 | 
Last Changed Date: 2011-04-03 14:27:39 -0400 (Sun, 03 Apr 2011) | 
Checksum: 2098e127a615e567234d2d09512e17ae | 
Conflict Previous Base File: conflictedFile.xml.r0 | 
Conflict Previous Working File: conflictedFile.xml.mine | 
Conflict Current Base File: conflictedFile.xml.r2

Answer (score 0):

The combination of your error message and the svn info you provided in your comment don't seem to tell the same story.

The info says that those 3 files including conflictedFile.xml.r0 should exist, but the r0 file is the previous BASE file, so you should only see it when you resolve to BASE.

The files shown in svn info should always exist when the conflict occurs, but any process can then change/remove them. Resolving to MINE should resolve to the .mine file.

Resolving to WORKING should always work but has a different result, but you can resolve the conflict yourself (by installing the right file) before resolving to WORKING.